# How can I identify this id in the json file

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
{\"id\":\"752e19d21ed6235098581c9b17164f7171520bd790bef1c9538268831f7ebef0\",\"variables\{\"id\":\"ern:product:uri:nike-sportswear-dunk-low-sneaker-low-whiteblack-ni111a0rh-q11\"}}":{
         "data":{
            "context":{
               "entity_id":"ern:product::NI111A0RH-Q11",
               "isReviewable":null,
               "family":{
                  "rating":{
                     "average":4.6404495,
                     "totalCount":178
                  },
                  "reviews":{
                     "totalCount":0
                  }
               },
               "flags":[
                  
               ],
               "brand":{
                  "name":"Nike Sportswear",
                  "entity_id":"ern:brand::NI1"
               }
```

So the problem I have right here is that the id changes every time I use a different link to scrape data. the only thing that doesn't change is ern:product which is also unique for this specific id.
At the moment I scrape it like this:

```
product_json['graphqlCache']['{\"id\":\"752e19d21ed6235098581c9b17164f7171520bd790bef1c9538268831f7ebef0\",\"variables\":{\"id\":\"ern:product:uri:nike-sportswear-dunk-low-sneaker-low-whiteblack-ni111a0rh-q11\"}}']['data']['context']['simples']
for i in all_skus:
        size_skus = i['sku']
```

But I can't use this on other products, so how could I fitler every id for ern:product? If its not detailed enough just let me know and I will add it, so don't close it immediately. Thanks in advance.